# accepts_nested_attributes_for/fields_for not doing anything

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, nested-forms, nested-attributes

I cannot get the attributes given in a nested form to take. I haven't been able to find any other posts related to this issue with my exact configuration:

Here are the abbreviated models. As you can see, the associations between Users and Organizations are a bit complex:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :confirmable

  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me
  attr_accessible :first_name, :last_name, :nickname
  attr_accessible :current_organization_attributes

  has_many :created_organizations, :class_name => "Organization", :foreign_key => :creator_user_id, :inverse_of => :creator_user
  belongs_to :current_organization, :class_name => "Organization", :foreign_key => :current_org_id # one-way relationship

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :current_organization
  ...
end

class Organization < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :creator_user, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => "creator_user_id", :inverse_of => :created_organizations
  ...
end
```

And abbreviated schemas:

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: users
#
#  id                   :integer(4)      not null, primary key
#  email                :string(255)     default(""), not null
#  current_org_id       :integer(4)
#  first_name           :string(255)
#  last_name            :string(255)
#  nickname             :string(255)
#

# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: organizations
#
#  id                      :integer(4)      not null, primary key
#  name                    :string(100)
#  creator_user_id         :integer(4)      not null
#  zip_code                :string(255)
#  phone_number            :string(255)
#
```

Here is the abbreviated view code (HAML):

```
#main
  %h1 Your account
  = form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name), :html => { :method => :put, :autocomplete => "off" }) do |f|
    = devise_error_messages!
    .edit-account-hold
      %span About you
      = f.label :first_name, "First Name"
      = f.text_field :first_name, :required => @contact_request_is_pending
      ...

    .edit-account-hold
      %span Your business
      = f.fields_for :current_organization do |o|
        = o.label :zip_code, "Zip Code"
        = o.text_field :zip_code, :required => @contact_request_is_pending
        = o.label :phone_number, "Phone Number"
        = o.text_field :phone_number, :required => @contact_request_is_pending

    .edit-account-hold
      %span Your password
      = f.label :password
      = f.password_field :password
      = f.label :password_confirmation
      = f.password_field :password_confirmation
      = f.label :current_password
      = f.password_field :current_password

      = f.submit "Update", :class => "orange-button border-radius"
```

Controller code:

```
def update
  if resource.update_with_or_without_password_as_needed(params[resource_name])
    set_flash_message :notice, :updated
    redirect_to after_update_path_for(resource)
  else
    clean_up_passwords(resource)
    render_with_scope :edit
  end
end
```

Here is a sample of the params that are passed when "Update" is clicked:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"8aL7bMJdVI2uaLt3WoZEraSB0U5iZgBvxYh5fwsQnqM=", "user"=>{"first_name"=>"Nick", "last_name"=>"", "nickname"=>"", "email"=>"nick@mycompany.com", "current_organization_attributes"=>{"zip_code"=>"12345", "phone_number"=>"1112223333", "id"=>"1000003"}, "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "current_password"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Update"}
```

The nested hash params["user"]["current_organization_attributes"] contains the attributes that are failing to save. Using the debugger within the server, I have confirmed that a call to

```
user.current_organization.update_attributes( the_above_mentioned_current_organization_attributes_hash )
```

at the appropriate time works great and updates the attributes just like I'd like. Why won't the system do this automatically? Is it something to do with the belongs_to relationship using alternate class names or foreign keys?

Help!

Answer (score 0):

IIRC, `accepts_nested_attributes_for` only works for `has_one` or `has_many` associations... at least, that's what a cursory glance at the docs reveals. I don't think it works on `belongs_to`.

My best suggestion is to change the association in the User model (and this requires schema changes as well) to do something like:

```
has_many :organizations
has_one :current_organization, :class_name => "Organization", :conditions => {:current => true}
```

Where the `organizations` table has a column called `current`, and validate that only one organization can be current, maybe with a callback that changes all other `current` values for that users' organizations to `false` if the column is updated (scoped to that user, obviously).

This should allow `fields_for` and `accepts_nested_attributes_for` to work as intended.

Comment: Hmm. In trying to get this thing working, I have come across many examples of people using accepts_nested_attributes_for a belongs_to association, and most of them seemed to be able to get it working. I will look into this issue again but I had previously been led to be led to believe that the two directives were compatible.